# Poor cache hit ratio for spatial tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance

Most PostgreSQL tuning guides introduce the cache hit ratio as a metric to find out if PostgreSQL has enough heap space to cache data and reduce heavy disk i/o. To get a hit ratio for a certain table you have to query `heap_blks_read` and `heap_blk_hit` for a certain table from `pg_statio_user_tables` and compare them over a certain time span (while using the table certainly).

You should have hit_ratios near 99% and for most normal tables I have no problem to tune postgres accordingly so that I am easily able to hit anywhere between 99 and 100%.

But if my table has a geometry column this is totally different, most of the time I am only able to hit 50% as a maximum (30% on average). I am aware, that geometries a stored differently in PostgreSQL (EXTENDED Storage via TOAST).

Does this affect caching? Are there other options to tune PostGIS?

Comment: Paul Ramsey has written about increasing the toast size and other options to improve spatial performance. Mostly this is due to spatial data being "wide" compared to the cache

Comment: @IanTurton so this caching behaviour was to expect for spatial tables? Thats what I wanted to clarify. I know some articles Paul wrote about EXTENDED storage, but not if it affects caching in general). If the answer is yes, you can answer this question regularely as I will accept that.

Comment: I'm speculating rather than answering with any knowledge which is why I made a comment instead of an answer